# Firebug - Search nested dom nodes

Tags: javascript, firebug

Is it possible to search nested dom nodes or buried deep inside nodes from dom tab  using firebug.

or

Is there any other tool does the same job.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug has a search box in the top right area.  This search definitely works on the DOM, but I believe it works in other panes as well.

[image]

### EDIT

Looks like this is a known issue:  [Searching in DOM Panel only works for displayed elements](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1545) .  You can star that bug to be notified of updates / changes.  I added myself to be notified and included a link to this question.  I plan on again updating this answer once the issue has been resolved at which time I can post the version of firebug this is available in.

Apparently firebug does have [console selectors](http://www.phpied.com/console-selectors/)  to aid in searching, but I'm not sure this will help you.

Comment: I have some dom decoration methods and properties in 'dom tab' ( not in html tab ). Currently in dom tab , search will be performed only in nodes which is opened or visible ones. I basically needs to search the one which is not opened..